# C++ Azure file upload: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: python, c++, azure

I'm trying to upload a file to my azure file service using the following C++ code (which is referenced from official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-c-plus-plus-how-to-use-files)):

```
const utility::string_t storage_connection_string(U("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;"
    "AccountKey=mykey"));

// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
azure::storage::cloud_storage_account storage_account =
  azure::storage::cloud_storage_account::parse(storage_connection_string);

// Create the Azure Files client.
azure::storage::cloud_file_client file_client =
  storage_account.create_cloud_file_client();

// Get a reference to the share.
azure::storage::cloud_file_share share =
  file_client.get_share_reference(_XPLATSTR("myfileservice"));

//Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
azure::storage::cloud_file_directory root_dir = share.get_root_directory_reference();

// Upload a file from a file.
azure::storage::cloud_file file =
  root_dir.get_file_reference(_XPLATSTR("my-sample-file"));
file.upload_from_file(_XPLATSTR("test.pdf"));
```

This gives out the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'azure::storage::storage_exception'

what():  Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

I've searched the internet and found it should be something related to authentication using SAS. I tried many example codes online but still cannot succeed.

However, I can do similar file upload by the following **Python** code `without SAS authentication` and without any trouble:

```
import os
from azure.storage.file import FileService, ContentSettings

currentDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#credentials for azure account
file_service = FileService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

#path for azure file
global pathStr
pathStr = 'https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileservice/'

#function for uploading file onto Azure container
def upload(myfile):
    file_service.create_file_from_path(
        'myfileservice',
        'files',
        test + '.pdf',
        myfile,
        content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='text/pdf')       
        )
print('finished uploading file.')
```

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Are you using SAS Token to upload in your C++ code or just account name/key?

Comment: Just account name and key in my C++ using my provided code in the question.

Comment: I was able to run the C++ code above without any problems. Please check for 2 things: 1) Account name/key combination is correct and 2) Check the date/time on the machine from where you're running this code. In my experience, these 2 are the most common reason for 403 error when using account name/key.

Comment: I've double confirmed that name/key combination is correct, and I don't think it's date/time problem since I extended the valid date of the token on azure portal to at least year 2020. Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm getting confused....You said that you're using account name/key but on the other hand you're talking about the token (which I am assuming is SAS token). The date you're talking about is the expiry date of the token validity which has nothing to do with the date/time on your local computer. To prevent replay attacks, Azure Storage returns 403 error if it finds that the token issued is too old. Typically a difference of +/- 15 minutes is allowed but beyond that you will start seeing that Azure Storage is rejecting your requests with 403 error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I talked about token because when I searched the internet about this error, I found it's related to it. However, what confused me is that I can upload the file to the same service using Python without any need to token. You asked about the date/time, so I specially looked at its settings in Azure portal via browser. What I'm trying to do is do the same thing as I did in my Python code, without SAS token, just by account name/key. Hope I explained my problem clearly.

Comment: Can you confirm 2 things for me please: 1) You're running both C++ & Python code from the same machine? and 2) You're using same account name/key in both C++ and Python code?

Comment: I double confirmed those two steps, no difference.

Comment: Hmmm...Totally weird! This is what my code looks like: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/464842ac5788006cc2301ae5e9b207b9 using which I am able to upload the files. Please see if it is any different than yours.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. I tried your code but got the same error. And I don't see any big difference between your and my code.

Comment: One more thing you could try is trace the request/response through a tool like Fiddler. In response you should see more details about the error. Please give that a try.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try now.